# Laravel - Using Values Returned from Middleware Group for Global Variables

Tags: laravel, global-variables, middleware

Background: I want to use the same code for multiple templated web sites. I want the code to identify the domain being accessed and then be able to set global variables to be used throughout the app.

At first, I created \config\global.php and had the logic in there working as expected:

```
$webUrl = url()->current();

/**************************************************
 * Set Conference name based on URL
 **************************************************/
$confId = 0;
$confName = '';
$confAbbrev = '';
if(strpos($webUrl, 'webdomain1') > 0) {
    $confName = 'Domain 1 Full Name';
    $confAbbrev = 'Dom1';
    $confId = 25;
}
elseif(strpos($webUrl, 'webdomain2') >0) {
    $confName = 'Domain 2 Full Name';
    $confAbbrev = 'Dom2';
    $confId = 35;
}
```

However, I eventually found that the "url()" was causing errors which prevented me from using "php artisan" commands throughout the app. After consulting my professional web developer co-worker, he said using a "global" config file for global variables was not best practice and recommended Middleware instead. He took control of my laptop and went REALLY fast...

In \app\Http\Kernel.php, he added the SetDomainVariables line at the end of $middlewareGroups:

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetDomainVariables::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

He then created a new file: \app\Http\Middleware\SetDomainVariables.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetDomainVariables
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        dd($request->getHttpHost());
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

The results of "$request->getHttpHost()" is what I need... it returns the "foo" of www.foo.com. However, I don't know how to assign this value to a variable and return it via "$next" and then how I can put logic around it to set my global variables that I can reference in a Blade partial, etc.

Thank you!

EDIT: If using the \config\global.php is really the right way to accomplish what I want, could I just comment out the "url()" line whenever I want to do a "php artisan" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to approach this problem, the easiest would be to make use of `config` -- which allows you to get and set configuration values dynamically.

1. Create a new file called `config/sites.php` containing an array for each of your sites, ensuring you start each domain with `www` and replace any `.` in the domain with `-` (because `.` in a config key will not work as Laravel uses a period to access child values).

```php
return [
    'default' => [
        'id' => 15,
        'name' => 'Default Full Name',
        'abbreviation' => 'Def',
    ],
    'www-webdomain1-com' => [
        'id' => 25,
        'name' => 'Domain 1 Full Name',
        'abbreviation' => 'Web1',
    ],
    'www-webdomain2-com' => [
        'id' => 35,
        'name' => 'Domain 2 Full Name',
        'abbreviation' => 'Web2',
    ],
];
```

You now have configuration values for each of your sites accessible anywhere in your application, e.g: `config('sites.www-webdomain1-com.name')`.

2. Add the following to your middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $host = str_slug(starts_with('www.', $request->getHttpHost()));

    $configuration = config("sites.{$host}") ?: config('sites.default');

    config(['site' => $configuration]);

    return $next($request);
}
```

You've now set the configuration value for the key `site` to the contents of the site configuration you set in `config/sites.php` for the request domain.

3. Anywhere you need to access the active site's configuration option use `config('site.property')`, e.g:

```php
Hello, welcome to {{ config('site.name') }}
```

There are better ways to approach this problem, personally I would create a `Site` model and then use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) however the way I've outlined here is very easy to set up for a beginner and should meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you. If I went this route, would I be able to connect to my DB in config/sites.php? The example I gave above (hard-coding ID, name, and abbreviation for each client web site) was more for just making sure I had data to test with. But I have a table in my DB where I could pass the domain name and dynamically bring back the ID, Name, Abbreviation, for the correct conference. Right now I'm at 2 clients, but if I get 10+ clients, I feel a single DB call (passing in the domain name) would be more scalable.

Comment: If you're doing this database driven then [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) is the correct approach, it is very easy. You create a subdomain route group ("Sub-Domain Routing" in the Routing documentation) and you create an explicit route model bind for the key you use in your domain route, e.g: `Route::domain('{conference}.example.com`)` and then `Route::bind('conference', ...)` -- all of this is covered in the documentation. Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: For future reference, when you're asking a question like this it's best to outline what you're trying to achieve first, e.g: "I have conferences in my database and I want each conference to have a page accessible via a unique subdomain which is determined by the `domain` property on the model, e.g: `conference.example.com` is Conference `id` 1" rather than outlining what your solution is / what you think is the solution. That gives people the information most necessary to helping you achieve your goals :)

Comment: I appreciate the input. I will try to implement your recommended changes within the next few days. One point of clarification... these will be separate domains, not subdomains of the same website. My first client website is www.pac7sports.org ... My second client will be a separate conference. But due to the nature of the content (sports scores, etc.), they will share the same database but be completely separate domains to which I plan on deploying the same exact code to minimize maintenance.

Comment: You do not need to deploy the same codebase multiple times, you can point multiple domains at the same Laravel installation and then use the domain (whether that's subdomains or full domains) to determine which data is loaded.

Comment: Thank you. I'm really close. I have your code working, but it will only display the Default section. I'm guessing when I'm at www.xyz.org it'd work, but right now I'm just using localhost/domain/public to test my page. So if www.pac7sports.org is my website and "pac7sports" is my localhost project "$request->getHttpHost()", how would I need to modify the sites.php code? I've tried a few combinations but can't seem to get it to work. I am sorry if these are simple questions... I've done a lot of PHP web development but this is my first time using MVC/Lavarel. ...

Comment: EDIT: $host = $request->getHttpHost() works. If my site is live and a user is at www.pac7sports.org, will this still work? Or will I need the longer version you gave?